# how to convert int to datetime in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, unix-timestamp

one table of my database in sqlserver have a column with type of int for store dates.

for example fields are: **1105275802**  or **1100330268**.

I can convert it to datetime in php with this code:

```
(int)date('U',1100330268);
```

I want convert this integers to datetime in sqlserver. how can i do?

thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert bigint (UNIX timestamp) to datetime in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904256/how-can-i-convert-bigint-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might be difficult since MS SQL run's on Windows systems and date('U') is "Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)".  I suppose you could probably calculate the DateTime, but it could get messed up if you don't account for the timezone change between GMT and your local timezone.

```
select DateAdd(second, 1100330268, '1970-01-01')
```

Comment: +1 Since a UNIX timestamp _is_ based on UTC, you're calculating the UTC time. Not a bad thing, it's pretty easy to convert from UTC to local time compared to doing it the other direction.