# Convert Unix time from IPFix to datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, unix, datetime, timestamp

I have an IPFix timestamp which appears to be in Unix time.  My SQL code is:

```
update 
  temp_ipfix 
set FlowStartTimeDT = dateadd(S, FlowStartTime, '1970-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Where `FlowStartTime` is the column containing the Unix timestamp.

A sample timestamp is `1410435197783`

The error I'm getting is:

> Arithmetic overflow error for type int, value = 1410435197783.000000.
>   The statement has been terminated

I tried the suggestions linked to this page, but the results are incorrect.  Month and Day are correct, but year is 2034.

```
select dateadd(s, (flowstoptime/1000), '1990-01-01 00:00:00') from temp_unix
```

Comment: please put the updates in your question and not the comment box\

Comment: What platform are you using? SQL Server?

Comment: Yes.  SQL Server 2014

Comment: Using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19979905/2589202) you can get around the limits.  Check out [my fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/51391/8)