# Date conversion from bigint to datetimestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Table (EVENTS) definition:

```
ID bigint, EVENTTIMESTAMP bigint
3361592,    132446022372460000
```

How can T convert this to date time stamp?
I know from another UI that the date time stored is `15-September-2020 10:10:37 AM`.

Can I get how to convert this using SQL queries for SQL Server?

What I tried:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT
          (
               CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, EVENTTIMESTAMP/100000000 ,'1970/1/1') AS DATE)
              ,' '
              ,CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, EVENTTIMESTAMP/100000000 ,'1970/1/1') AS TIME)
          ) EVENTTIME
FROM EVENTS
where ID = '3361592';
```

Comment: Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 14
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030474/sql-using-dateadd-with-bigints

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select *,
dateadd(s, convert(bigint, EVENTTIMESTAMP) / 100000000, convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00'))
FROM EVENTS
where ID = '3361592'
```

Comment: Returns the following 2011-12-21 09:37:03.000  what was expected is 15-September-2020 10:10:37 AM.   Is there some issue with calculation or UTC conversion?