# Converting a bigint timestamp/TIMESTAMP_MICROS to datetime2 in Azure SQL Server doesn't work - error Arithmetic overflow converting expression to int

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, biginteger, arithmetic-overflow

I am loading the New York Trip data (https://www.nyc.gov/site/tlc/about/tlc-trip-record-data.page) from parquet files to to an Azure SQL database.
The date is in the format TIMESTAMP_MICROS, what seems to be a timestamp as bigint. I could load the data to SQL Server.

Now I want to add a persisted computed column to convert the timestamp to a datetime.
For the normal SELECT from the TOP 1000 the following query shows the proper format:

```
SELECT TOP 1000
CONVERT
    (
        datetime2,
        DATEADD(S,[tpep_dropoff_datetime] / 1000000, CONVERT(datetime,'1970-01-01',120))
    )
AS [pickup_datetime_]
FROM [dbo].[NYTaxi]
```

I tried to add a computed column with the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NYTaxi]
    ADD [pickup_datetime] AS
    CONVERT
    (
        datetime2,
        DATEADD(S, CAST(CAST([tpep_pickup_datetime] AS BIGINT) / CAST( 1000000 AS INT) AS INT), CONVERT(datetime,'1970-01-01',120))
    ) 
    PERSISTED;
```

But I always get the following error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Does anyone have an idea why the error happens? How can I solve that?
If a date would be in the wrong format, I would also be happy to return a NULL value instead.

Comment: `DATEADD` expects an `int` not a `bigint`. If the expression for your second value overflows an `int` it will cause an error when passed to `DATEADD`.  Unfortunately, though there is a `DATEDIFF_BIG` there is not `DATEADD_BIG`, so you'll need to make the value smaller first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert unix epoch timestamp to TSQL datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507649/convert-unix-epoch-timestamp-to-tsql-datetime)

Comment: I'd suggest finding out what your bad values out first though. YOu can do with something like `SELECT tpep_pickup_datetime FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE TRY_CAST(CAST([tpep_pickup_datetime] AS BIGINT) / CAST( 1000000 AS INT) AS INT) IS NULL AND tpep_pickup_datetime IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: Perhaps these answers will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030474/sql-using-dateadd-with-bigints

Comment: @Larnu I divide the BIGINT by 1 million and CAST it to INT. So I don't see a point that is not working here

Comment: As we can't run you code, we can only guess. If you provide a [mre] we can give a more definitive reason. The fact remains that you *are* getting a value greater than an `int` can hold. You might believe you are, but the error says otherwise.

Comment: @Larnu your approach with TRY_CAST helped! I had a few rows with a wrong date (about 60 years in the future). Like that I could figure that out. Now I check if the date is in the past, then I transform the formula, if the date is in the future I return a NULL.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine for now.

```
DECLARE @tpep_pickup_datetime varchar(20) = '2147483647000000'

SELECT DATEADD(S, CAST(CAST(@tpep_pickup_datetime AS BIGINT) / CAST( 1000000 AS INT) AS INT), CONVERT(datetime,'1970-01-01',120))
```

Returns `2038-01-19 03:14:07.000`.

Any higher and you hit the "[Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)" but as `tpep_dropoff_datetime` is

> [The date and time when the meter was disengaged.](https://www.nyc.gov/assets/tlc/downloads/pdf/data_dictionary_trip_records_yellow.pdf)

And the data set is for NYC taxis, not time machines, so you should be fine for now.

> I would also be happy to return a NULL value instead.

You can use

```
DATEADD(SECOND, TRY_CAST(CAST(tpep_pickup_datetime AS BIGINT) / 1000000 AS INT), '19700101')
```

to convert these massively outlying values to `NULL` with no error and also use this expression to identify rows to look at in more detail (just garbage data or something else going on?).