# T-sql issue with coverting bigint to datetime

Tags: t-sql, casting

I have bigint value **635107999009730000**. 
I'm using this statement to convert this bigint to datetime:

```
select dateadd(second, 635107999009730000 /1000 + 635107999009730000 % 1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101')
```

I'm getting overflow error. Looks like dateadd function just cannot handle this bigint value.

How can I convert **635107999009730000** to datetime?

**635107999009730000** value is grabbed from Microsoft LYNC 2013 database and I don't really know what datetime this should be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert bigint (UNIX timestamp) to datetime in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904256/how-can-i-convert-bigint-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: Actually I don't think that is Unix time. Says "invalid date" when I try that in an [online converter](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be off the mark here but that value looks like nanoseconds and if that is the case you just have to divide it by a billion to get the seconds and add it to the unix time:

```
select dateadd(second, 635107999009730000 / 1000000000, '19700101')
```

You will have to test this against you data.

Comment: I found out what datetime value 635107999009730000 contains - it's 30.07.2013 16:51:40. Your example gives 1990-02-15 18:53:19.000. I used c# and standart DateTime constructor, which takes ticks as parameter. So, I believe that 635107999009730000 is tciks count. Also I found out that 10 000 000 ticks per second is used when creating DateTime from 635107999009730000.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today. Both  user1016945 and Suroh are correct to a degree. It is 10^7 ticks per second staring with 0001-01-01. So I slightly modified Suroh's statement. Since i'm not SQL expert, it's clumsy, but it work. You will lose seconds though. It overflows if I try to include seconds:
dateadd(year, -2000, dateadd(minute, 635107999009730000 / 600000000, '2001-01-01'))

I subtract 2000 years because I don't know how to pass 0001-01-01 to SQL. :)