# How to convert time which is in GPS format to Local time format in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatetime

This is the data packet which was received from android mobile to my server.

```
  $|351746051743568|12.9399604|77.6257631|0.0|1392979784822|1|#
```

In which following is the time which is received from the device: 1392979784822.
Since this is in GPS format, I tried to convert into local format in SQL and failed.
Please guide me in this issue.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904256/how-can-i-convert-bigint-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like unix/epoch time in millisecs?

```
declare @x bigint = 1392979784822
declare @msin1day bigint = 3600 * 24 * 1000

select dateadd(ms, @x % @msin1day, dateadd(day, @x / @msin1day, '19700101'))

(No column name)
2014-02-21 10:49:44.823
```

Comment: Beware - if that really is GPS time then it isn't the same as unix time. There's a rather involved explanation here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/90839/what-are-satellite-time-gps-time-and-utc-time