# GPSTime format conversion MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, gps-time

I have data received from my GPS device in below format.

```
GPSTime
448711.634985699
448711.654969689
448711.67494868
448711.69489767
448711.714907661
448711.734891652
```

I tried the query as per this link [Convert GPSTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936148/how-to-convert-time-which-is-in-gps-format-to-local-time-format-in-sql)
But didnt work.

Can someone shed some light on it ?

Comment: It would be helpful to figure out how to convert them if we knew what are the target values in human-readable datatime

Comment: Clearly it's not your regular [variant date](https://planetcalc.com/7027/) as it's off by over a thousand years. Using the variant date converter on any of these values results in a datetime somewhere in the 32 century... Even assuming you're off by a factor of 10 (meaning your decimal divider should be between both `1` digits you get a future date (2022).

Comment: According to [this page](https://www.andrews.edu/~tzs/timeconv/timedisplay.php) your GPS-Time *448711.634* would translate to *1980-01-11T04:38:31* in UTC. I doubt, that this (or your value) is correct... Please clarify...

Comment: Though if you are off by a factor of ten (move the decimal divider to between both 1 digits) the same page gives out dates in today's date - March 1st 2019 -  so is that the thing?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Don't understand this... According to the given page 1st of March 2019 is *1235433618*. This seems to be just the running seconds starting with the 6th of May in 1980.

Comment: https://www.oc.nps.edu/oc2902w/gps/timsys.html

Comment: @Hadi I've found the same page, but it seems to be a bit more complicated, than just to add seconds straight to a base date of `1980-05-06`...

Comment: @Duffer GPS time is an integer. What you posted is *not*. Where did those values come from and what do they represent? Without that, the question will have to be closed as it doesn't provide any information

Comment: I wonder why this epoch was chosen... But yes, I agree with Shnogo and Panagiontis - this does not look like gps time.