# Need to convert the date format from '06/10/2014 5:33:32 PM' to '2014-10-06 17:28:44.000

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to convert the date format from `06/10/2014 5:33:32 PM` to `2014-10-06 17:28:44.000` format

guide me Please ...

**QUERY**

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(22),'06/10/2014 5:33:32 PM', 120)
```

**RESULT**

`06/10/2014 5:33:32 PM`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Try to convert unix time and reformat as you need.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904256/how-can-i-convert-bigint-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-in-sql-server Maybe help you.

Comment: You should try to avoid doing any string manipulation of values that ought to be `date`s down in the database, if possible - keep them in `datetime2` columns/variables and let client libraries translate those into the appropriate data types in the client programs accessing the database, and only actually convert into a string when presenting it to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below sql query will work :

```
select CONVERT(datetime,'06/10/2014 5:33:32 PM', 101)
```

As per @Damien_The_Unbeliever comments, If OP treats `06` as day and `10` as month

```
select CONVERT(datetime,'06/10/2014 5:33:32 PM', 103)
```

**[Please follow the link for SQL Date formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)**

Comment: Since the OP's desired output is `2014-10-06 17:28:44.000`, and only SQL Server in insane mode believes that anyone would think that such a date was `yyyy-dd-mm`, I think the `06` is meant to be the day and `10` the month. Therefore `101` is probably wrong and `103` might be more appropriate.