# Date between condition on epoch time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, epoch

I have a column in `startTime` in my table which is an epoch time. I want to impose date between condition for give date.

```
SELECT 
    *, DATEADD(SECOND,startTime,'1970-01-01') 
FROM 
    [dbo].[State] 
WHERE
    startTime BETWEEN DATEDIFF(s,'19700101 05:00:00:000','12-01-2015') 
                  AND DATEDIFF(s,'19700101 05:00:00:000','13-01-2015')
```

Here `startTime` is unix time column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a conversion function that converts from unix time to datetime 
this answer has such a function
[How can I convert bigint (UNIX timestamp) to datetime in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904256/how-can-i-convert-bigint-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-in-sql-server)

```
declare @startdate datetime ='2015-01-12'
declare @enddate datetime ='2015-01-13'


select *
from state
where fn_ConvertToDateTime(startTime) between @startdate and @enddate
```