# How do I generate an array of hours from a pair of timestamps in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table that looks like:

```
ID   start_time     end_time     username
1    1451674800     1451692800   blah
```

And I want a table that looks like:

```
ID   username   hours
1    blah       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Where [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16] is an array with values corresponding to the hours (PST) which lie between 1451674800 and 1451692800 (UNIX time).

My thought is that I need to use Hive's timestamp functions, but I am so incredibly unfamiliar with Hive and especially with the timestamp functions that I don't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

First create function which convert UNIX time to ordinal time. Can take from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904256/how-can-i-convert-bigint-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-in-sql-server.)

Then calculate DATEDIFF(hh,start_time,end_time). Add this number of hours begining from DATEPART(dd,start_time) and concatenate them.

Comment: DATEDIFF is exactly what I need, thanks! Doesn't [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/date-functions-in-hive.html) accomplish UNIX -> Ordinal conversion?

Comment: Ah, DATEDIFF in hive only works on differences between dates, not times.