# How to convert Unix time in microseconds with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unix-timestamp

I've seen a lot on converting Unix time from other formats to datetime, but nothing really from microseconds. How can you SELECT a field this with a timestamp of 1470562081943371 without getting overflows with an output of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:MM?

Comment: can you use bigint?

Comment: Yes, that's what it would be stored in.

Comment: so then...select it? i just created a variable of type bigint, stored the number and selected it with no problem. Not sure what your real issue is...

Comment: The question is how to convert it to datetime from Unix time in microseconds. I guess I didn't specify.

Comment: quick search reveals... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904256/how-can-i-convert-bigint-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: That one is not for microseconds. Unix timestamp overflows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is unit is correct, but...

```
Declare @UnixTime bigint = 1470562081943371
Select DateAdd(MS,round(((@UnixTime/1000000.)-(@UnixTime/1000000))*1000,0),DateAdd(SECOND,(@UnixTime/1000000),'1970-01-01 00:00:00'))
```

Returns

```
2016-08-07 09:28:01.943
```

Confirmed results with http://www.epochconverter.com/

[image]

Comment: @Fastidious Well that's encouraging.   Le'ts hope you can confirm the time portion.   If you don't care about milliseconds, just strip off the first DateAdd(MS...

Comment: Yeah, milliseconds is important.

Comment: Thanks, all confirmed. Like I said, others are not on this granularity of time that I could find. Good to know about the same on this granularity too.

Comment: @Fastidious Well done.  Now you get move on the next item on your list.  :)