# How to get count by day in My SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

This table contains count of orders by hour in time stamp:

orders

```
id, created_at, items
1, 1484827200, 5
2, 1484830800, 10
3, 1484913600, 10
```

// how to get count of items by day?
something like that:

```
2016-01-19, 15
2016-01-20, 10
```

my query:

```
SELECT sum(items)
FROM orders
GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY_HOUR FROM created_at)
```

is not correct.

```
SELECT day(from_unixtime(created_at)), sum(items)
FROM orders
GROUP BY day (from_unixtime(created_at))
```

too slow.

Comment: Your title says `count by hour` but your solution that is "too slow" groups by days .

Comment: sorry for that, fix

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Add a String Column called "Day" that is also indexed

Ideally you should include a day column, and update all your rows. Storing your datetimes as unixtimestamps and converting them every time causes the following problems:

- You have to run from_unixtime for every row, and then also extract the day.
- You are sacrificing any sort of optimizations that may work correctly with an indexed column. Unix `timestamps` are `numbers` and are essentially apples to oranges when compared to dates.

So I would just add a `day` column if this query is critical, and save the day along with the timestamp in order to get the maximum speed. Also index your day column.

### 2. Experiment

- Try possibly using a aliased table, and then doing the group by. I have a feeling the optimizer optimizes in such a way that it may not make a different but you may be running from_unixtime 2 times instead of once (this needs to be checked):

  SELECT
    day,
    SUM(items)
  FROM (SELECT
    DAY(from_unixtime(created_at)) AS day,
    items
  FROM orders) AS temp
  GROUP BY temp.day

I'm not sure if the `from_unixtime` conversion was being run again in the `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want sum by on hours then use this query

```
 SELECT id,created_at,SUM(items) FROM orders GROUP BY HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at));
```

And If you want sum by on dates

```
 SELECT id,created_at,SUM(items) FROM orders GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at));
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I found a question which could help you: [How can I convert bigint (UNIX timestamp) to datetime in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904256/how-can-i-convert-bigint-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-in-sql-server)

One of the solution in the answers use

```
Select
dateadd(S, [unixtime], '1970-01-01')
From [Table]
```

To change unixtime to a timestamp.
It could be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do variants on `GROUP BY LEFT(datetime, 13)`.  That expression returns a sortable/groupable string that works well for date+hour:

```
+---------------------+-----------------+
| NOW()               | LEFT(NOW(), 13) |
+---------------------+-----------------+
| 2017-01-20 14:44:42 | 2017-01-20 14   |
+---------------------+-----------------+
```

Of course, as already mentioned, you need to first convert from unixtime.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could help you.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE t GROUP BY DATE(t.createddatetime)
```