# Integer to Datetime SQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, integer

I need convert this integer "1469416462" to datetime in format dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss . Any ideas?

My Intent:

```
select CONVERT (datetime,1469416462)
```

Comment: which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: what would be the expected date of 1469416462?

Comment: phpmyadmin (mysql) v5.1.63

Comment: You'll might find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904256/how-can-i-convert-bigint-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: I expect 2016-07-25 05:14:22

Comment: @AlexisCervetto ok, i got it right. see my posted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value 1469416462 looks like a Unix-Timestamp. 
Unix-Timestamp: Seconds since 1.1.1970
So the solution would be easy like:

For MySQL:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(1469416462)
```

Comment: FUNCTION MydataBase.DATEADD does not exist

Comment: @AlexisCervetto i just changed it. before the question was not tagged with mysql!

Comment: This works! thanks you dude!

Comment: @AlexisCervetto: Perfect! Don't forget to mark the anser as accepted, so other users can find the working solution