# TSQL convert numbers to time

Tags: t-sql

I have a time field which is storing numbers in '49235062'. Can these be converted to an actual readable time?

This does not look anything like a time stamp.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the number coming from. What makes you think that it is a timestamp?

Comment: If you consider this number as a unix timestamp (seconds since Jan 01 1970. (UTC)), it _could_ correspond to 07/24/1971 @ 8:24pm (UTC)

Comment: There's a possible answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904256/how-can-i-convert-bigint-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-in-sql-server) if it is a unix timestamp.

Comment: @peter the field name is called CRT TIME and is stored as a varchar. The CRT DATE does not show the time.

Comment: @pac0 tried the unix time conversion but it returned error saying;

Comment: @Pac0 Spot on with UNIX timestamp

Comment: @PeterSmith actually, if the field is only labelled "time", I'm betting on [John Cappelletti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58121239/479251)

Comment: Without solid evidence it is impossible to tell which is correct; the name of a field is not enough. Do you have any external supporting evidence? I come back to my original comment: what is the source/origin of the number?

Comment: Nope, I don't have evidence, that's why I used the verb "bet" ;) .The question indeed lacks context / additional information. However, the *hint* that makes me bet in favor of John's answer instead of my original hypothesis, is that the unix timestamp would imply also a change of several days, or even months, to get only a time at the end. That _looks_ unprobable to me. But this just an opinion, maybe completely wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Just a guess, but is this milliseconds from midnight?

**Example**

```
Select dateadd(MILLISECOND,49235062,0)
```

**Returns**

```
1900-01-01 13:40:35.063   -- 1:40 PM
```

If so, then it is a small matter to convert to time or format as time

Comment: Perfect, thanks. The time marries with the front end application. If I add in the column, an error Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function. How do I correct this?

Comment: Amended to format(dateadd(MILLISECOND,cast(c.[CRT-TIME] as int),0), 'HH:mm:ss') [CRT-TIME]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a UNIX timestamp (number of seconds since 1/1/1970), try the following:

```
DECLARE @timeStamp varchar(10) = '49235062'

SELECT @timeStamp, CONVERT(TIME, dateadd(S, CAST(@timeStamp AS int), '1970-01-01'))
```

Produces the following

```
49235062    20:24:22.0000000
```

So your time is `20:24:22` which is the answer that @pac0 suggested.