# How can I select data from this week using a Unix timestamp in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause

I have two columns in my database named `dtp_s` and `dtp_e`. Both of these columns hold `strtotime()` formatted ints which I then use in my PHP application to calculate hours/minutes between time intervals.

I want to display the 5 most recent records in date order, which works fine when I use this:

```
SELECT id
FROM _records
ORDER BY dtp_s DESC
LIMIT 5
```

However, I now want to convert the `dtp_s` back to a DateTime format in my Query and only pull out the data for that week. The issue I have is the records are for a weekly quota, my idea of pulling 5 records out covers Monday-Fri (which is all that is needed and uploaded) however, the following Monday will show the previous weeks Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday as well.

I tried to use `date_sub` for a one week interval but this seems to only work on DateTime datatype columns, not a Unix timestamp:

```
SELECT id
FROM _records
WHERE dtp_s > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
ORDER BY dtp_s DESC
LIMIT 5
```

How only select the data that is from the current week by converting my formatted DateTime back to DateTime format? I appreciate any help in advance.

An example of my `dtp_s` and `dtp_e` is: `1595570400` `1595584800`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the filter value to a unix timestamp with [date function `unixtimestamp()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp), like so:

```
where dtp_s > unix_timestamp(now() - interval 1 week)
```

Comment: I Googled if there was a Unix timestamp conversion about 50 times and was just hit with posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904256/how-can-i-convert-bigint-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-in-sql-server) - Thank you so much! I'll mark this when I can - it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can directly use `unix_timestamp()` with no conversion:

```
where dtp_s > unix_timestamp() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Although `unix_timestamp()` can be very useful, `unix_timestamp(now())` is actually redundant.  You can just do the whole calculation in the domain of unix timestamps.