# Convert unix timestamp to date in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert the 10 digit unix timestamp  value to proper yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format using the code in Microsoft SQL server

```
Update data
set Time_final= dateadd(S,[unix_date], '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0')
from data
```

But I am not getting the output in the desired format. For example:

for the value 1599313801 which we are supposed to get 2021-04-17 14:25:59, I am getting 13:50:01.0000000

Comment: That would suggest that `time_final` has a type of `time` rather than `datetime` of some sort.

Comment: `select dateadd(second, 1599313801,  cast('1970-01-01 00:00:00.0' as datetime))`  is `2020-09-05 13:50:01.000` . Why expect something else?

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest that you just do this as a computed column:

```
alter table data add real_date as (dateadd(second, unix_date, '1970-01-01'));
```

The value is then computed when you *query* the table.  You don't have to worry about the values getting out of synch.

Comment: Depending on the requirements, it might also be worth persisting this column too. (Though you'll have to add an explicit convert and a style code to do so.)

Comment: As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904256/how-can-i-convert-bigint-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-in-sql-server) shows `DATEADD` suffers from the Y2038 problem. The two-part conversion in the answer would fix that. So would a SQLCLR call to `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds`